# Rails 3.2 Param lost after Validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm rather new to rails.

I have a _form where I get a param (asset_id) for a dropdown by a link_to:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="icon-fire"></i>'.html_safe, new_mastering_path(:asset_id => asset.id) if file_exists(asset) %> </td>
```

This is the form:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="asset_selector">
  <%= f.label :asset_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:asset_id, @available_assets, :id, :name, :selected => params[:asset_id]) %>
</div>
```

When the validation of the form has an error the param is lost and the dropdown selection is wrong.

What do I have to do to retain the param?

Comment: It should be :selected => params[:model_object][:asset_id]

Comment: thanks - and what would :model_object be?

Comment: here f is instance of which model? so that model_object would be replaced there.

Comment: Another one on this: now, when I redirect to this form from a page without passing the param I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" Can I somehow select just if the param is available/passed?

Comment: simply do :selected => (params[:object].present? && params[:object][:asset_id].present?) ? params[:object][:asset_id] : " "(nil)

Comment: thanks - solved it like this:  :asset_id ? {} : {:selected => params[:mastering][:asset_id]}